# To make 5% Credit card hold/Authorization on Woocommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, authorize.net, woothemes

I am using Authorize.Net CIM from WooThemes on my site.

http://www.woothemes.com/products/authorize-net-cim/

My client sells Gold/Silver coins and use only "Payment by Cheque" as Payment method. But to be sure that user can pay and in case of non-payment, they want to authorize/hold 5% of Cart Total from user's Credit Card until payment is made (within 7 days).

Plugin allows card authorization, can anyone suggest how can I Authorize credit card for a certain amount?

Comment: http://www.wpmayor.com/adding-deposits-partial-payments-woocommerce-site/ check if it helps . its a paid plugin to do partial payments

Comment: @ris thank you for the response mate. I've checked it, but it will not serve our needs. I need to authorize only. 5% of the total cart value.